# Dynamic String replacement in a list for SQL 2005

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2005

I have a column that can have results like the following:

```
ER

ER,ER,ER

ER,ER,OR,OR

OR

OR,OR

OR,OR,OR,ER,ER
```

I am looking for a way to replace any a string such as `"ER,ER,ER,OR,OR"` to just `"ER,OR"`.  No matter how many times `ER` or `OR` show up I just want each displayed only once.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a split function (or search for hundreds of variations on this site):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML]
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a 
      CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Then you can do this:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(foo VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x SELECT 'ER'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ER,ER,ER'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ER,ER,OR,OR'
UNION ALL SELECT 'OR'
UNION ALL SELECT 'OR,OR'
UNION ALL SELECT 'OR,OR,OR,ER,ER';

;WITH g AS 
(
  SELECT x.foo, s.Item
    FROM @x AS x 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(x.foo, ',') AS s
    GROUP BY x.foo, s.Item
)
SELECT original = x.foo, new = STUFF((SELECT ',' + Item FROM g
  WHERE foo = x.foo GROUP BY Item 
  FOR XML PATH(''), 
    TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
  FROM @x AS x;
```

Results are almost exactly the way you want, except order from the initial string is not preserved:

```
original          new
----------------- ----------
ER                ER
ER,ER,ER          ER
ER,ER,OR,OR       ER,OR
OR                OR
OR,OR             OR
OR,OR,OR,ER,ER    ER,OR
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be like this... though it's limited to the example you provide in the question only.  Conceptually there are better ways as provided in the comment to your question by KM.

```
update mytable 
set mycolumn = 
case when (mycolumn like '%er%' and not mycolumn like '%or%') then 'ER'
when (mycolumn like '%or%' and not mycolumn like '%er%') then 'OR'
when (mycolumn like '%er%' and mycolumn like '%or%') then 'ER,OR' end
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a safe assumption that there are only ever two values. Add a couple more values and this update statement gets pretty complex, pretty fast. :-)

Comment: agreed, and why I said it's limited to the scenario proposed in the question only

Comment: Just wanted to state it in addition in case people grab the code without reading the context, a comment might help. :-)